# Amazon EC2 instance can not be reached after reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I restarted my EC2 instance and now I am not able to ping it, ssh it or open it on my browser. However in my management console I could see the instance as up and having no problem.

Comment: Did you enter the new IP when trying to connect to the instance after restart? Do you run a firewall on that instance?

Comment: Can be "just one of those things" http://serverfault.com/questions/326467/what-to-do-with-suddenly-unreachable-non-logging-ec2-instance

Answer (score 1):

Amazon instances change names sometimes between restarts, double check the public dns name that you are using, chances are that it has changed.

If it has not changed (double check, copy paste if possible) then double check the firewall settings, I've seen situations where the firewall settings get mucked up after a restart (very rare) - simply adding to the firewall configuration should do the trick.